# Bootstrap 4 library name in Libman (CDNJS) from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, package-managers, libman

How do you add the Bootstrap 4 library to a project using Libman as package manager and CDNJS as provider, it doesn't seem to be in the list of avaliable libraries?

Is it named something else compared to Bower & NPM?

In this case, I am using a .net Core project with Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap) page:

> twitter-bootstrap

Comment: The reason seems to be legacy. The first version has had this name indeed ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Provider **unpkg**

[image]